# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick while function is available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am amzaed on this error don't know what is the problem, it super simple but i am unable to find that why function is not calling instead it showing refrence error

```
ProjectQueue.php:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: QuoteUnsuccessful is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (ProjectQueue.php:1)
```

my function given below, it is in separate JS file which i reference correctly.

```
function QuoteUnsuccessful(projectQueueId){

        console.log("QuoteSuccesfull make upcomming "+projectQueueId );
}
```

while the html

```
<input type="button" value="successful" class="btn btn-danger   " onclick="QuoteUnsuccessful(1)">
```

Comment: Check external js file place properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your js file is inserted in html before input tag.

```
<script>
  function QuoteUnsuccessful(projectQueueId){    
    console.log("QuoteSuccesfull make upcomming "+projectQueueId );
  }
</script>    
<input type="button" value="successful" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="QuoteUnsuccessful(1)">
```

But I recommend you use addEventListener insted of onclick attr.